# Drupal 7 hook_cron - where to put it

Tags: php, drupal, cron, drupal-7

I want to add cron jobs to my Drupal 7 system, but I can't figure out how. The examples I've read on Google doesn't explain at all where to put your code. Do you have to do a module in order to use the my_module_cron()?

I have a block which uses some data received from a remote place. A cron job fetching these remote data is what I need to do. Can't I add my cron job in the code for my block?

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to create a custom module, yes. See the [module developer's guide](http://drupal.org/developing/modules) for information on exactly how to do this...when you've got a module installed this will work:

```
function mymodule_cron() {
  // Do something
}
```

Comment: I got it working - thanks for your reply :) I think it is a pity that you have to do modules in order to add cron jobs.. It seems a bit overkill.

Answer (score 1):

Create a custom module and necessary is module name.info and module name.module.
I that module name.module file write hook function named hook_cron().with in the function you can write you cron jobs regarding code and get you goal please try it.

syntax:

```
 function hook_cron() {

 // write your custom code here.

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put `hook_cron` function in `.module` file, but as per good practice should use `hook_cron_info` function together and with queue module by this we dived cron load in different queue.

For example in `hook_cron` we populate queue and in `hook_cron_info` we defile queue and its call back. it reduce load like nothing.